# What happens if you forget your 1Password password?

Tags: passwords, password-management

When using a service like 1Password, what happens if you forget or lose your master password?

My guess is that you can simply reset your passwords on all the sites 1password remembered for you, but I think if you don't have a recovery email address or phone, things like gmail accounts might be rendered permanently inaccessible. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work for 1Password. Unlike most services, we cannot reset or recover your 1Password Master Password. And so you really, really need to make sure that you don’t forget your Master Password or lose your Secret Key.

There are some things that we recommend.

1. Please make a copy of your Emergency Kit and keep it in a safe place that you can get to, if, say, your computer dies.
2. With a family or business 1Password account certain other members of your family or organization can havE some recovery powers.

It is heart breaking when people write in telling us that they’ve lost the ability to decrypt their data. I don’t regret our security design, which makes it impossible for use to decrypt anyone’s data, but it does have consequences.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have an up-to-date backup, you will permanently lose access to all the data stored by 1Password.

There is no way for 1Password to decrypt the data, simply because they don't know the key. Your password **is** the key to the AES encryption used.